# The 'style' attribute is not declared

Tags: java, c#, xml, visual-studio, xamarin

The code blocks in my activity_main.xml with the errors are as follows:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/editText_style"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:id="@+id/editText1" />
<EditText
    style="@style/editText_style"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />
```

The code in my styles are as follows:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="editText_style">
      <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/editText_background</item>
      <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
      <item name="android:ems">10</item>
      <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'm getting the error stating:
The 'style' attribute is not declared.
I dont understand what is wrong. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try clean and rebuild solution, please.

Comment: You can ignore the warning.

Comment: The style is underlined though. It appears like as if it is some big issue. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.